# Mapping types for Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to map an old SQL table in Grails and I find for example that : boolean is mapped into tinyint and not BIT like as stated in the hibernate reference (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm)

I know I can force it by giving the sqlType as constaint but I want to know to what types Grails really map. it would be great if someone gives a list of all types or point to a reference.

here are the 2 Tables :

**Original Table**

[image]

**New Table**

[image]

Comment: Boolean is mapped with a bit and Byte is with tinyint , read the doc you mentioned above properly.

Comment: @NitinDhomse no it doesn't I have tested it

Comment: you need to publish your domain class in order to see if it's well defined

Comment: @PabloPazos Thank you for your interest in my question, unfortunately I don't have access to the code any more.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean`/`boolean` is mapped to BIT. Please check the reference carefully.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm

[image]